# How to code a scrollable list that works correctly on Android browsers? (HTML)

Tags: android, html, scrollable, html-lists

I have the following HTML, mostly generated on the fly using JS, as a dynamic popup that appears when you click in several points on a map.

```
<div class="bubble">
<span class="topPaisCont"></span>
<span class="globalContent">
    <h1>ASIA</h1>
    <div class="contPais">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/flags/asia.png" style="visibility: visible; "> Asia
        </a>
        <br>
        <!-- A few more <a>s with the same structure -->
    </div>
</span>
<a class="close"></a>
</div>
```

I'd post an image but it seems I can't since I'm a new user...

The scrollable list of links is rendered correctly in most PC browsers and also on the iPhone and iPad, where it can be scrolled swiping one or two fingers.

However, I can't make it work on Android, where it can't be scrolled down.

Can you help with this? Is it the way it's implemented? 
I can post the CSS if needed.